# can any one tell me any thing about this book

Tags: translation

Can any one tell me any thing about this book? All I can gather is

- Mülheim a. d. Ruhr : Verlag von Julius Bagel
- Subjects Folk songs, German.
- Gedenkemein is translated to Johnny jump up
- Liebe is love and

which may be incorrect
[image]
german book

[image]

Comment: I am afraid this site is not translation service. Hence, I vote to close this question.

Comment: Can you please more precise, what do you want to know? A transcription? A translation? Or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

On the title page (which is your 2nd pic):

> Gedenkemein.
>
> Stammbuchverse und Sprüche
>   der
>   Liebe und Freundschaft.
>
> Mühlheim a. d. Ruhr,
>   Verlag von Julius Bagel.

On the other page (your 1st pic)

> Stammbuch-Verse und Sprüche.
>
> Schlage nur mit der Wünschelrut’
>   An die Felsen der Herzen an ;
>   Ein Schatz in jedem Busen ruht,
>   Den ein Verständiger heben kann.
>   <sub>Rückert</sub>
>
> Wer früh erwirbt, lernt früh den hohen Wert
>   Der holden Güter dieses Lebens schätzen ;
>   Wer früh genießt, entbehrt in seinem Leben
>   Mit Willen nicht, was er einmal besaß ;
>   Und wer besitzt, der muß gerüstet sein.
>   <sub>Goethe</sub>
>
> So lang ist keine Nacht,
>   Daß endlich nicht der helle Morgen tagt.
>   <sub>Shakespeare</sub>

»Gedenkemein« (Other name: »Vergissmeinnicht«) is the name of a [little blue flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosotis_arvensis), and this names mean »Think of me« (the other name is »Don't forget me«). So the title of this book is: »Think of me«

*Stammbuch* = friendship book
*Stammbuchverse* = verses in a friendship book

*Mühlheim a. d. Ruhr* is a city in Germany

*Wünschenrut’* is the shortened form of *Wünschelrute*, which is *divining rod.*

I think you can find all other words in a dictionary.

Comment: Following is a thought only. It seems to me there is a typo in the old book. (Shakespeare) : *No night is so long that in the end no new morn smiles.* => *So lang ist keine Nacht, Daß endlich nicht der helle Morgen **lacht** instead of *tagt*.

Comment: Minor correction: the flower's common name is actually ["forget-me-nots"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosotis) in English, a direct translation from the German Vergissmeinnicht.

Comment: @help-info.de: Nice find, translation can be verified [here](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/macbeth-2182/1) in the line before *Fünfter Akt*. It is also a more convincing rhyme by far.